# webpack error — sockjs-node connection refused

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I get this error when I upload my site to my webserver:

```
http://desktop-gq7oerj:3000/sockjs-node/info?t=1489850537555 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

[image]

my webpack config is:

```
 entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://' + require("os").hostname() + ':3000/',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
],
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is your server listening on port 3000?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way I can find out? As the error is coming from my dev server, do I even need it running in production?

Comment: You say you're uploading it to your webserver? Webpack-dev-server is not for production use. What you should do is use webpack to build production code and upload those. You then setup a node/nginx server to serve the static files.

Comment: If you use docker check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65523561/4248573
it may be related

Answer (score 1):

In my case,it worked this => Here's [a link](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserversocket)

in webpack.config i aggregated :

```
devServer: {
      socket: 'socket',
      ...
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
entry: production
        ? './src/index'
        : [
            `webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:${SETTINGS.PORT}`,
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            './src/index',
        ],
```